# Why am I getting "python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2) but it is not installable" on Raspian Wheezy?

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed Indigo on Raspian Wheezy on the Raspberry Pi using the excellent article http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi

The ROS system functions well; but, when I try to install

$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install tightvncserver
or
$ sudo apt-get install vsftpd

I get the following errors

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
python-catkin-pkg : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2) but it is not installable
python-rosdep : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2) but it is not installable
python-rosdistro : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2) but it is not installable
python-rospkg : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

I’m a relative NOOB to Linux. Is there any guidance?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199112/why-am-i-getting-%22python:any-(%3E=-2.7.1-0ubuntu2)-but-it-is-not-installable%22-on-raspian-wheezy?/) by [arnoldbail](https://answers.ros.org/users/19638/arnoldbail/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-12-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the work-around/bypass in [raspberry pi with ROS Indigo ( or any new Release of ROS)](http://answers.ros.org/question/192250/raspberry-pi-with-ros-indigo-or-any-new-release-of-ros/)

I edited /var/lib/dpkg/status deleting the python:any segments.

---

Originally posted by [arnoldbail](https://answers.ros.org/users/19638/arnoldbail/) with karma: 36 on 2014-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [emccarron72](https://answers.ros.org/users/21125/emccarron72/) on 2014-12-17**:
I keep bumping my head on this, but can't find "python:any" in the mentioned file...  Tried a few variants, but nothing seems to pop up.  Thoughts?

**Comment by [Alvar](https://answers.ros.org/users/21018/alvar/) on 2014-12-21**:
Same problem, I cannot find it too

**Comment by [Sergio MP](https://answers.ros.org/users/542/sergio-mp/) on 2015-02-02**:
Similar problem. Since it seems that the unmet dependency is the one about python (  **Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)**  ) I tried checking my version with

```
python -V
```

But it responds: Python 2.7.3. So it's higher that 2.7.1. Could it be something about the "-0ubuntu2" part?

**Comment by [kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/22505/kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com/) on 2015-05-21**:
I have the same problem. Any workaround??

**Comment by [TomJacobs](https://answers.ros.org/users/22616/tomjacobs/) on 2015-06-02**:
Me too, anyone figure it out?

**Comment by [rbaleksandar](https://answers.ros.org/users/14216/rbaleksandar/) on 2015-08-23**:
This is big issue omho. I seem to be unable to use catkin_make because of this! And yes, I can't find anything like that indicated in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer to this problem is quite simple (ok, it took me two days until I read the complete article http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi and found the correct hint):

Just befor section "2.3 Building the catkin Workspace" is a box with the following note:

> Note: Rosdep may report that
> python-rosdep, python-catkin-pkg,
> python-rospkg, and python-rosdistro
> failed to install; ***however, you can
> ignore this error because they have
> already been installed with pip.***

---

Originally posted by [SebastianStigler](https://answers.ros.org/users/23408/sebastianstigler/) with karma: 11 on 2015-07-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rbaleksandar](https://answers.ros.org/users/14216/rbaleksandar/) on 2015-08-23**:
It tells you to ignore `Failed to detect successful installation of ...` and not to ignone unmet dependencies and broken packages **facepalm**